# DNS Pointer to old server name

Tags: windows-server-2003

We have a SBS2003 server that was migrated to a new hardware platform, the computer name has changed but the domain is the same.  The desktop's are trying to do offline files to the old server name.  There is a nslookup entry for the old server name and a DNS entry for the old server.

How do we safely remove the old DNS entry without breaking the computer offline folder storage locally.

Can we change the pointing location on the offline file storage to point to the new server name.

Answer (score 1):

You can not. Offline storage runs by computer name. What you can do is have clients retire the offline storage (i.e. remove the shares) then reopen them with the new server name.

Altenratively you could CNAME the old name to the new server's name, so sync should / would work.